# Что означает строчка "ошибки" при выводе расширенной информации о процессе в MAC OS

Tags: macos

Что означает строчка "ошибки" на экране детализации информации о процессе (см. скриншот) в приложении "Мониторинг системы"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ошибкой" в данном случае называют состояние `Page Fault`. Современные операционные системы с виртуальной памятью используют это состояние, в частности, для организации выгрузки неиспользуемых страниц памяти на жесткий диск компьютера.

Если страницы, к которой обращается программа, в памяти нет, происходит `Page Fault` (и счетчик, который вас напугал - растет). Программа замораживается, страница подгружается с диска обратно в память, программа размораживается.

Вывод - этот счетчик показывает, насколько активно используется страничная подкачка на диск. Чем меньше, тем лучше. Уменьшить можно, увеличивая объем оперативной памяти.